# Polybar on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, statusbar

Is there a way to install `polybar` on Ubuntu 14.04. I checked the package on [UbuntuUpdates](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/polybar) and it only has packages for `xenial` and `yakkety`. Is there a way to run it on `trusty`?

Answer (score 0):

If there's no package for it, you'd probably have to find the source and build it yourself, also supplying any dependencies, likely by building them as well.

Others will most likely suggest you should upgrade to 16.04 instead, but that's your decision.  However, if (like me) you're not really up to building software that's not available for your version, all you can really do is make a backport request and hope someone is willing and able to provide a package in the backports repository.